# What are the consequenses of reporting criminal damage by my partner?

Tags: united-kingdom, vandalism, criminal-damage

My domestic partner - we are unmarried - has maliciously destroyed a computer belonging to me (approx value £2000) following an argument. I don't want to respond in kind, but I want to send a signal that this is not acceptable behaviour.

If I report criminal damage to the local police, will this be taken seriously? And is a prosecution automatic or will I need to press charges? I don't actually want to end our relationship (we have young children) but I want this incident officially logged.

Comment: Honestly, you should think very seriously about whether you want to stay in the relationship. The bigger question is not whether the local police will take it seriously, but whether you will take it seriously. Leaving the premises with the kids for a while, or insisting that your partner leave the premises for a while (and perhaps not cohabiting again until there is an apology and compensation paid), may be a more useful way to make a statement that will be understood as real if you don't want to end the relationship. If your partner isn't willing to do that to save the relationship, leave.

Answer (score 3):

If the police become aware of the domestic violence through you reporting it or otherwise the matter is entirely in their hands. They will decide if they want to prosecute or not.

Comment: The matter could also be referred to social services leading to an abuse and neglect investigation with respect to the children. Prosecutors don't entirely ignore a victim's wishes but certainly aren't bound by them either.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually not posting about domestic violence at all, unless you are informing me that destruction of my property is a type of violence?

Comment: Absolutely it is